# Can I set allow_push globally for all Mercurial repos servied by one hgwebdir?

Tags: configuration, mercurial

Our company has a large number of projects that have gone from VSS to Subversion, and now I'd like to move them to Mercurial.  Thus far, I've gotten `hgwebdir.cgi` working (Apache on Windows).  At the moment I have to add `allow_push = *` to the .hg/hgrc of each repo in order to push changes.  Is it possible to set this option globally on the server, so that we wouldn't have to edit every repository if changes were made in the future?

I've tried `hgweb.config` and `Mecurial.ini` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System default global settings are stored under `c:\Mercurial\Mecurial.ini`  This file and directory are not created by the Mercurial installer, so you have to do it manually.

This should also be supported in `hgweb.config` come version 1.3.

(Thanks to djc on freenode#mercurial)